# How to have blank A5 landscape paper size?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am using JasperReport Studio 6.20.0 , JDK 18 on Windows 10 pro x64. How to have blank A5 landscape paper size?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin template for A5 paper size.

What you can is to start with Blank A4, then select the report/root node in the Outline, go to the Properties view, click Edit Page Format at the bottom and choose A5 as Page Format.

[image]